# Get max date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How do I get the 'max' date from the following table using MySQL?

```
date_time
-----------------------------
Wednesday, 21 July 2010 20:41:51
Tuesday, 19 October 2010 16:7:41 
Tuesday, 29 November 2010 16:7:41
```

I want to retrieve the maximum date from the table.

Comment: What is the date column data type? Is it varchar?

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mysql> select str_to_date('Wednesday, 21 July 2010 20:41:51', '%W, %d %M %Y %T');
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('Wednesday, 21 July 2010 20:41:51', '%W, %d %M %Y %T') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2010-07-21 20:41:51                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[`str_to_date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Don't reinvent the wheel, stored the column in `date-time`

```
alter table your_table add column new_date_time datetime;
update your_table set new_date_time=str_to_date(date_time, '%W, %d %M %Y %T');
alter table channge column date_time ditch_date_time varchar(255);
alter table channge column new_date_time date_time datetime;
```

To get max value

```
select max(date_time) from your_table;
```

If you like to keep `varchar` (good luck with that)

```
select max(str_to_date(date_time, '%W, %d %M %Y %T')) from your_table;
```

Comment: oh.. thank u very much. I kept the field in varchar format only, it's working.

Answer (score 1):

If running max on that format doesn't work I guess you could try to reformat it in the query to a format that will allow max using [date format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). As long as the column is corretly formated you should be able to just do an order by desc though.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM date_time ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y %M,%d') DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That would be my next answer then. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 1):

The only possible solution is to store the date in the **proper** format.
So, change your field type to `datetime`

Comment: I wouldn't say its the only possible solution, but it is the best solution.

Comment: @seanieb when you will have enough practical experience, you will learn that not to follow lame misconcepts coming from laziness and ignorance, and to correct these issues as soon as possible, is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date_time FROM TABLE ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 1
```

This will work when your date_time field is of the type DATETIME or whatever other date specific type there is.

Comment: Actually the date_time field type is varchar

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT mydate
FROM mytable
ORDER BY mydate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Or just

```
Select max(mydate) from mytable
```

Comment: i never store date in database using varchar. why someone do that ?

Comment: Up-voting this as it's the best way to get the max date/datetime. You should never store it in varchar format anyway.